# java.net.InetAddress gets localhost address wrong (WinXP)

Tags: java, networking, groovy

I'm working in Groovy 1.8.6, running on JDK 1.6.0u33. When my program is starting up, it attempts to connect to another process on the same host by connecting to a telnet port on the host address. It uses the standard Java class InetAddress to determine the local host address. However, for some reason when I start the program up on a Windows XP VM, the host address resolves to garbage and the connection fails.

The startup script includes this line for diagnostic information:
`def serverAddress = "http://${InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress}:${config.ServerPort}/DigitizerService?wsdl"`

The output when `serverAddress` is printed to the terminal is:
`http://0.1.0.5:8989/DigitizerService?wsdl`

The address is not always the same- another time it came out as `0.2.0.5`. But it always comes out as something that's not even a valid address, let alone the actual address for this host.

This same codebase is in production on a large number of boxes out in the wild and I've never seen an issue like this coming up, so I guess it must be specific to this new devbox it's on- or it's a bug in the new JDK.

Does anyone have *any* idea what might be causing something so basic as this to output garbage? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other process isn't listening on **127.0.0.1**?

Comment: It is, but that's really not the point. java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost() is returning an invalid IP, that's very concerning whether I can code around the problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I tried restarting before posting this question (of course, this is Windows after all), and it did not help, a second reboot of the VM seems to have fixed the issue. It was in the process of installing a big pile of Windows updates, as it was an old VM that I'd just dusted off, so I suppose that may have somehow scrambled things internally in the OS.

So I'm still very confused as to how this came about, but I think I can conclude that it was not Java at fault. Probably.